# i:Interaction.Triggers inside of DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been using i:Interaction.Triggers and an EventToCommand implementation to handle certain control events in my VM.

```
<DataGrid ...>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="AutoGeneratingColumn">
        <ui:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AutoGeneratingColumnCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
```

All worked fine. Then I needed to have multiple DataGrids, so I created a ItemsControl template that has the DataGrid with the interaction triggers. I noticed in this case, the triggers are not working.

Is this a known issue? I debugged the EventToCommand class and it is calling the Attach member, but it never calls the Invoke.

The ItemsControl looks like:

```
<ItemsControl>
   <ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate>
<DataGrid ...>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="AutoGeneratingColumn">
        <ui:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AutoGeneratingColumnCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
```

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding StoredProcedureResults}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
                        CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="AutoGeneratingColumn">
                        <UI:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AutoGeneratingColumnCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="LoadingRow">
                        <UI:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.LoadingRowCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: An ItemsControl template that has the DataGrid?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, I have updated the question. Works fine as a standalone DataGrid, but not inside of an ItemsControl.

Comment: Can I see the XAML, please? Enough to test what you're actually doing. This seems like a much better case for a UserControl than for whatever this is.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have added a more complete portion... the EventToCommand is part of my MVVM framework and the 2 commands are just RelayCommandT implementations. It worked as a standalone DataGrid, not sure why it doesn't inside of a ItemsControl.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Gonna get this to work with an attached property / behavior I guess unless you find the issue :), but I'm thinking its probably one of those random WPF flukes that don't work as they should :).

Comment: Ah OK, now I understand what you meant about the ItemsControl, forget what I said about usercontrols. Is it successfully binding the command to the attached property? I mean, the relative source binding and all that is working? But then the command never executes?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, the stored proc returns 2 result sets. I get 2 DataGrids, columns and rows all show in both DataGrids. The 2 command getters are both called twice each. In the EventToCommand class, the OnAttach method is hit 4 times. Just the Invoke method is never hit so it never invokes the commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combination of an issue with `System.Windows.Interactivity` EventTrigger and some circumstances.

#### Interactivity.EventTrigger can't handle an event fired before FrameworkElement.Loaded event

It internally uses associated object's Loaded event to attach event handlers for all events except the Loaded event itself. `OnAttached` method from your `EventToCommand` is called from `TriggerAction.Attach`, which actually attaches `TriggerAction` to the associated object (DataGrid here). `AssociatedObject` property on `TriggerAction` is not a DependencyProperty, and as `TriggerAction` inherits from `Freezable`, this method does freezable related stuff (calls `WritePreamble` and `WritePostscript`). The actual event handlers have not been attached yet.

#### DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn and LoadingRow

If ItemsSource can be determined when DataGrid is initialized (DataGrid can figure out which columns and rows it needs to generate), these events fire before the Loaded event. I assume that when your DataGrid was not part of DataTemplate, it's ItemsSource was bound to a property on VM whose value was null at the time DataGrid is initialized. Once you moved your DataGrid to DataTemplate, when you set `ItemsSource` property of your ItemsControl and DataGrids are initialized for each ItemControl's Item, DataGrid's `ItemsSource` can be determined during initialization and these events fire before the Loaded event. If you allowed users to add rows to your DataGrid (`IsReadOnly` to false, and `CanUserAddRows` to true), your `LoadingRowCommand` would be executed after `DataGrid.IsLoaded` becomes true and user adds a row.

To get this to work you would have to not set DataGrid's `ItemsSource` within DataTemplate (basically remove `ItemsSource={Binding}`), wait for the Loaded event and then set it. I'd say that goes against the idea of item template (and is there a nice way to do this?), so I would go for attached behaviors for these two events as you suggested in your comment.

Comment: Great explanation.. thanks! In answer to your question, yes, the standalone DataGrid.ItemsSource was bound to StoredProcedureResults (as the ItemsControl is now). That value was null until the user clicked a button to execute the SP. When I moved to the ItemsControl to handle multiple result sets, ItemsControl.ItemsSource was pointed to the array of DataTables which would have values and such and jive with your explanation.