# Binding DataTemplate items events to command in viewmodel

Tags: wpf, xaml

Iam Building WPF MVVM app that has a listbox which its item template has combobox and textbox (the item template is in separate resource dictionary), i binded the selectionchanged event and textchanged event in template to a command in my viewmodel and it is working perfectly at runtime, but the problem is that at design time it gives me triggers.null error and the xamlview doesn't show but gives me XamlParseException.

i Tried CommandtoEvent in MVVMlight and it didn't work, also tried AttachedCommandBehavior and didn't work also, moreover tried moving the whole template to the view (as an item template in the view instead of resources dictionary but that didn’t work either.

It sounds like interactivity gives this error when placed inside template but i dunno how to to work around it

The attached Xaml code is for the datatemplate of the Listbox

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AllPanelsFilter">
    <Grid Margin="0 0 30 0" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding AllConditionsList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCondition}" >

                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged" >

                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ApplyAllPanelsFiltersCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor} }"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SearchTextBox}" Text="{Binding SearchString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ApplyAllPanelsFiltersCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}  }"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        </TextBox>

    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I get this error >> 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox'.'Triggers' is null.

Here is the ViewModel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ViewNewPanelsPair> AllViewNewPanelsPairs { get; set; }
    public ViewNewPanelsPair CurrentViewNewPanelsPair { get; set; }
    public View CurrentView { get; set; }
    public ViewsFilter ViewsFilter { get; set; }
    public ViewsFilterCommand ViewsFilterCommand { get; set; }
    public AddAllPanelsFilterCommand AddAllPanelsFilterCommand { get; set; }
    public RemoveAllPanelsFilterCommand RemoveAllPanelsFilterCommand { get; set; }

    public ApplyAllPanelsFiltersCommand ApplyAllPanelsFiltersCommand { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<AllPanelsFilter> AllPanelsFilters { get; set; }


    private AllPanelsFilter selectedAllPanelsFilter;

    public AllPanelsFilter SelectedAllPanelsFilter
    {
        get { return selectedAllPanelsFilter; }
        set
        {
            selectedAllPanelsFilter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("selectedAllPanelsFilter");
        }
    }



    public LevelPanelsViewModel(List<FamilyInstance> allPanels, List<FamilyInstance> oldOanels, List<ViewNewPanelsPair> allViewNewPanelsPairs, View currentView)
    {
        this.FilteredAllPanels = new ObservableCollection<FamilyInstance>(allPanels);
        this.AllPanels = new ObservableCollection<FamilyInstance>(allPanels);
        this.OldPanels = new ObservableCollection<FamilyInstance>(oldOanels);
        this.AllViewNewPanelsPairs = new ObservableCollection<ViewNewPanelsPair>(allViewNewPanelsPairs);
        this.ViewNewPanelsPairs = new ObservableCollection<ViewNewPanelsPair>(allViewNewPanelsPairs);
        this.CurrentView = currentView;
        this.ViewsFilter = new ViewsFilter();
        this.ViewsFilterCommand = new ViewsFilterCommand(this, this.ViewsFilter);
        this.ViewsFilterCommand.Execute(null);
        this.CurrentViewNewPanelsPair = this.ViewNewPanelsPairs[0] ; // makes first view selected at startup
        this.AllPanelsFilters = new ObservableCollection<AllPanelsFilter>();
        this.AddAllPanelsFilterCommand = new AddAllPanelsFilterCommand(this);
        this.RemoveAllPanelsFilterCommand = new RemoveAllPanelsFilterCommand(this);
        this.ApplyAllPanelsFiltersCommand = new ApplyAllPanelsFiltersCommand(this);


    }

    public LevelPanelsViewModel()
    {

    }
    public void DragOver(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        GongHelper.DragOverCopy(dropInfo);
    }

    public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        GongHelper.DropDefault(dropInfo);
        //GongHelper.DropCopy<FamilyInstance>(dropInfo);
       // CurrentViewNewPanelsPair.IsViewPanelsNotEmpty = CurrentViewNewPanelsPair.SelectedNewPanels.Count > 0;
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

Here is the command class:

```
public class ApplyAllPanelsFiltersCommand : ICommand
{
    public LevelPanelsViewModel VM { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<AllPanelsFilter> AllPanelsFilters { get; set; }
    public List<FamilyInstance> TemporaryAllPanels { get; set; }

    public ApplyAllPanelsFiltersCommand(LevelPanelsViewModel VM)
    {
        this.VM = VM;
        this.AllPanelsFilters = VM.AllPanelsFilters;
        this.TemporaryAllPanels = new List<FamilyInstance>(VM.AllPanels);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.TemporaryAllPanels = new List<FamilyInstance>(VM.AllPanels);
        foreach (AllPanelsFilter AllPanelsFilter in AllPanelsFilters)
        {
            string FilterText = AllPanelsFilter.SearchString;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterText))
            {
                switch (AllPanelsFilter.SelectedCondition)
                {
                    case AllPanelsFilter.Contains:
                        TemporaryAllPanels = TemporaryAllPanels.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(FilterText.ToLower())).ToList();
                        break;
                    case AllPanelsFilter.DoesNotContain:
                        TemporaryAllPanels = TemporaryAllPanels.Where(x => !x.Name.ToLower().Contains(FilterText.ToLower())).ToList();
                        break;
                    case AllPanelsFilter.BeginsWith:
                        TemporaryAllPanels = TemporaryAllPanels.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(FilterText.ToLower())).ToList();
                        break;
                    case AllPanelsFilter.DoesNotBeginWith:
                        TemporaryAllPanels = TemporaryAllPanels.Where(x => !x.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(FilterText.ToLower())).ToList();
                        break;
                    case AllPanelsFilter.EndsWith:
                        TemporaryAllPanels = TemporaryAllPanels.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(FilterText.ToLower())).ToList();
                        break;
                    case AllPanelsFilter.DoesNotEndWith:
                        TemporaryAllPanels = TemporaryAllPanels.Where(x => !x.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(FilterText.ToLower())).ToList();
                        break;

                }
            }

        }
        //clear all panels observable collection
        int count = VM.FilteredAllPanels.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            VM.FilteredAllPanels.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        //sort temporary list
        TemporaryAllPanels.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
        //fill observable collection from temporary list
        TemporaryAllPanels.ForEach(x => VM.FilteredAllPanels.Add(x));
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


}
```

AllPanelsFilter Class:

```
public class AllPanelsFilter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public const string Contains = "contains";
    public const string DoesNotContain = "does not contain";
    public const string BeginsWith = "begins with";
    public const string DoesNotBeginWith = "does not begin with";
    public const string EndsWith = "ends with";
    public const string DoesNotEndWith = "does not end with";
    public List<string> AllConditionsList { get; set; }


    private string searchString;

    public string SearchString
    {
        get { return searchString; }
        set
        {
            searchString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SearchString");
        }
    }

    private string selectedCondition;

    public string SelectedCondition
    {
        get { return selectedCondition; }
        set
        {
            selectedCondition = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCondition");
        }
    }



    public AllPanelsFilter()
    {
        this.SearchString = "";
        this.AllConditionsList = new List<string>() { Contains, DoesNotContain, BeginsWith, DoesNotBeginWith, EndsWith, DoesNotEndWith };
        this.SelectedCondition = Contains;
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Set the `DataTemplate.DataType` property: `DataTemplate DataType="MyViewModelType"  />` for designer support during design time.

Comment: @BionicCode , Thanks for your fast reply, i did this  `<DataTemplate x:Key="AllPanelsFilter" DataType="{x:Type VM:LevelPanelsViewModel}">`  but unfortunately it didn't work !!

Comment: Given that the code is building and executing and only the designer shows false errors you could try to clean and rebuild the solution and restart VS. On which type is `ApplyAllPanelsFiltersCommand` declared, `LevelPanelsViewModel`?

Comment: @BionicCode , Answering your question : Yes `ApplyAllPanelsFiltersCommand` declared in `LevelPanelsViewModel` , and i tried cleaning and rebuilding and restarting VS but that didn't work either.

Comment: @BionicCode  to figure out what is causing the problem i tried this : I started new WPF project from scratch and tried adding interactivity inside and a template and that worked fine at design time and runtime but i discovered that the new project has AnyCpu processor architecture , i converted it to X64 (same as my original project ) and it gave me the same error again , but the problem is that when i reverted back to my original project and changed it from x64 to AnyCPU hoping that this solves it , for my surprise it didn't solve the issue !!! , iam really confused and out of ideas.

Comment: I think the reason that the version of interactivity dll iam using doesn't support X64 , is there a version of expression blend sdk that supports X64 ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with x64 support. Based on your first comment I assume that the  `DataTemplate` for the `ListBoxItem` targets the data type `LevelPanelsViewModel` . If this is the case then your bindings inside the trigger didn't resolve. I doubt that the item's `DataContext` equals the `DataContext` of the `Window` element. The binding must become this: `<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ApplyAllPanelsFiltersCommand}" />`. Since your example doesn't provide enough context information I can only assume.

Comment: @BionicCode DataContext is set at xaml by this line `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type={x:Type vm:LevelPanelsViewModel}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"` and at the initialization of the window by this code behind `levelPanelsWindow.DataContext = levelPanelsViewModel;` and by the way i get intellisense for the command now in the resource dictionary data template after adding datatype as per your advice

Comment: But still the application builds and runs, right? Are there any errors in the output window? Any exception when you run it in debug mode?

Comment: @BionicCode The application builds but with the same design error "Null Triggers" and it runs without errors at runtime but the command don't work (it doesn't invoke).

Comment: Go to Debug/Options/Debugging/Output Window/WPF Trace Settings  and make sure "Bindings" is set to Information or Warning. Then start the debugger and observe the Output Window. Select an item from the combo box. Does it show any binding errors? It must be that binding. Are you sure the Command exists on the binding source and is properly initialized and not null?

Comment: @BionicCode i added the code of the viewmodel in the original post so u can make sure that the command is initialized and declared correctly , also the debug option is set to warning , i started the debugger as u adviced but no errors where shown in the output window

Comment: @BionicCode i added the command class also to the original post so u can have a look on it

Comment: @BionicCode problem solved, really thank for backing me up and sharing ideas with me that lead to the solution

Comment: Nice. I just wanted to ask you about the version of your Expression.Blend.Sdk. Better install libraries with NuGet in future. It will give you the latest version and also tracks installed packages for updates . This makes things a lot easier.

Comment: Right click the project that requires the package in your Solution Explorer and select "Manage NuGet Packages...".

Comment: @BionicCode , the old one was 1.02 , the new one is 2.0 but i didn't find the new one in the Nugetpackage manager that's why i installed the new sdk and added the dll as a reference in the project

Comment: @BionicCode , i searched for that and installed it before, it gave me the same old design time error , the only one that didn't was the one with the Sdk , i will try to dig more in the Nuget to see if it is there

Comment: @BionicCode Removing itemssource from the listbox solved the problem, but don't know where to put the itemsource to ensure binding at runtime without having this error

Comment: I thought you fixed the problem by using a different version of the Blend SDK? It has nothing to do with the Binding. Binding works and the interactivity triggers too. It must be something with your code. You have to look at your code very closely. Check if everything is initialized again. Check the binding source, I think it's the property of `AllPanelsFilter`? Check the whole class. If you say it works when you remove the binding then it must be the source. But I am confused because you said it worked after changing to a different SDK version.

Comment: @BionicCode ... it worked on my laptop and still working !!! ... but it doesn't work on my PC !!!! Although i used the same SDK version on my PC (Actually i copied the whole solution from my laptop to PC ) and still working on my Laptop and not my PC ... i digged more .. i found a post with the same issue that its solution was that it gives that error coz at design time the itemssource of listbox is bound to viewmodel property that is NULL and the event trigger is hooked at the template so whenever xaml parser tries load itemssource at designtime it hooks the event to a Null itemssource !!

Comment: @BionicCode surprising enough when i removed the itemssource from listbox it worked !!! ... the problem is i dunno where to put itemssource ... have a look at this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230118/iinteraction-triggers-inside-of-datatemplate

Comment: That's why I asked you to check the binding source again. It must be initialized properly the moment you instantiate it (`AllPanelsFilter`?). Please just do it. Your code snippets doesn't show the instantiation. There is no reason to omit the `ItemsSource`. As I said before the binding works and the triggers do too. Everything works except the code that you authored. That's why you have to revisit it.

Comment: @BionicCode ... i did attach the whole viewmodel before in the post and as u can see AllPanelsFilter is instantiated in viewmodel constructor by this line this.AllPanelsFilters = new ObservableCollection<AllPanelsFilter>(); .... if there is a certain code that u wanna see tell me and i'll update the post ... another exclamation here ... why it is completely working fine on my Laptop thought it is the same solution and project and Nugets and dll references on my PC and Laptop ??!!

Comment: @BionicCode i added the `AllPanelsFilter` class code to the post so u can see if there is something wrong

Comment: @BionicCode ... i solved it ,,, for some reason u have to install the whole package Development Kit (SDK) for .NET 4 and run the installer not just get the dll and reference it ... that solved it on my PC

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by using the interactivity dll in the Microsoft Expression Blend Software Development Kit (SDK) for .NET 4 , which can be downloaded here : "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801" , the problem was simply that the old interactivity dll doesn't support x64(which was my project architecture) but this new one does . Thanks for @BionicCode for helping me by sharing ideas and supporting me up since the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Removing itemssource from the listbox solved the problem, but don't know where to put the itemsource to ensure binding at runtime without having this error